# Bad operand types for binary operator '+' because of arraylist type

Tags: java, arraylist

So, I have java as my course this semester and I am facing much problems while learning it.
Here, I have to write a program to calculate average of arraylist elements. I have all classes written (as according to requirement of question) and the error lies here so far. Can anyone help me with it?

```
public int aveScores(ArrayList<ScoreInfo> sList)
{
    int sum = 0;
    if(!sList.isEmpty())
    {
        for(ScoreInfo s : sList)
        {
            sum += s;
        }
    }
    return sum/ sList.size();
}
```

error link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHl1U.png

Comment: You are trying to add type `ScoreInfo` and a type `int`. That doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`ScoreInfo` is not a numeric type, so you can't add `s` to your sum.

You probably need something like :

```
    for(ScoreInfo s : sList)
    {
        sum += s.getScore(); // assuming ScoreInfo class has a getScore method
                             // that returns an int
    }
```